# Why isn't this loop to detect correct variable names working properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Variables names must start with a letter or an underscore.
condition = False
#Lets check whether the first character is either a letter or an underscore.
if name[0].isalpha():
    condition = True
elif name[0] == '_':
    condition = True
else:
    condition = False
    pass

# Set condition to False just so it's more readable for me.
#Lets check the rest of the elements starting after 1 to see whether 
#they don't contain a non-letter, number or 
#underscore
for e in name[1:]:
    if e.isnumeric() or e.isalpha() or e == '_':
        condition = True
    else:
        condition = False
return condition
```

So basically it returns True or False whether the variable name supplied is valid or not. Can someone give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How come you aren't returning as soon as you already know the answer?

Comment: Basically, the current code is checking if your last character of `name` is matching your required condition or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is inside the loop `for e in name[1:]:`. Every time through the loop, you will set `condition` to either `True` or `False`, *regardless* of what the original value was. You probably want to exit the loop as soon as `condition` turns false.